# Odd scrolling sidebar behavior in Firefox

Tags: css

I'm creating an app with a scrolling sidebar, but it's acting a little strangely when I use Firefox: the content in the sidebar disappears somewhat below the top of the div if the mouse is lower in the sidebar, and disappears correctly when the mouse is in the top of the sidebar.

[image: under Firefox, the top of sidebar disappears below the top of the div when I scroll with the mouse in the lower part of the div, although it behaves correctly when the mouse is in the top part of the div]

This isn't the end of the world, but I'd rather have my app not behave oddly to Firefox users.

Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="fixed-body">
  Test
</div>
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="menu-header">
    Menu
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae mauris in lacus vestibulum facilisis non at mauris. 
  </p> 
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae mauris in lacus vestibulum facilisis non at mauris. 
  </p> 
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #DDFFDD;
    color: #005500;
}   

h1 {
    font-size: 2em;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
  }   

  #fixed-body {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #AAAAFF;
    width: 75%;
    height: 90%;
  }   

  #scrollable {
    height: 100%;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left: 75%;
    margin-top: 10%;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-y: scroll;
  }   

  #menu-header {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 5%;
    padding: 3px;
    background-color: #F80;
    font-size: 1.8em;
    font-weight:bold;
  }

  p { 
    margin: 10px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
  }
```

And a link to a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/threerightangles/os1b48ou/

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `overflow-y: scroll` to `overflow-y: auto` on `#scrollable`:

**[External JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/Syden/os1b48ou/5/)**

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #DDFFDD;
  color: #005500;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}
#fixed-body {
  position: fixed;
  top: 10%;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
  width: 75%;
  height: 90%;
}
#scrollable {
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: 75%;
  margin-top: 10%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
#menu-header {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 5%;
  padding: 3px;
  background-color: #F80;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  font-weight: bold;
}
p {
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>
<div id="fixed-body">
  Test
</div>
<div id="scrollable">
  <div id="menu-header">
    Menu
  </div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae mauris in lacus vestibulum facilisis non at mauris.
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc vitae mauris in lacus vestibulum facilisis non at mauris.
  </p>
</div>
```